# Updating column only if row exists using Python through MySQLdb

Tags: mysql

How do I UPDATE a column in a MySQL-table if and only if a row with a corresponding column "id" exists?

Example of my table:

```
id | name
---------
1  | NULL
2  | NULL
```

Example of my data (CSV):

```
1, Peter
2, Martin
3, Bob
```

I want Peter and Martin in the table. But I want Bob to be ignored. My query I came up with looks like this:

```
"UPDATE table SET name = %s WHERE id = %s"
```

But what would happen while doing:

```
"UPDATE table SET name = 3 WHERE id = Bob"
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't do anything. Your `WHERE` clause is the conditional. When the condition isn't met, the update doesn't occur.

Comment: That means it is save to run the code then. Thanks for your response!